# streaming multiple series to highcharts

Tags: json, dynamic, highcharts, series

I'm using websockets to stream valid JSON to highcharts.js.  My goal is to chart a few lines simultaneously on the same graph.  The JSON, which I control, contains data 4-16 series (called parsers) that I'd like overlay with highcharts.  Example of JSON:

```
[
    {
        "y": 91,
        "x": 1403640998,
        "name": "parser1"
    },
    {
        "y": 184,
        "x": 1403640998,
        "name": "parser2"
    },
    {
        "y": 26,
        "x": 1403640998,
        "name": "parser3"
    }
]
```

I can get a single line to graph, but they get combined into a single series.  I'd like to dynamically adjust the series based on the number of parsers I'm monitoring.  If my JSON contains information for 3 parsers, like I posted above, I'd like to see 3 lines automatically update every second.

As you can see, I can only get 1 to show.
[image: screenshot of my single line]

My HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    var $message = $('#message');
                    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://x.x.x.x:8888/ws');
                    var self = this;

                    connection.onmessage = function(event) {
                        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
                        var series = self.series[0];
                        var redrawVal = true;
                        var shiftVal = false;
                        if (series.data && series.data.length > 25) {shiftVal = true;}

                        var newseries = {
                            name: '',
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0
                        };


                        $.each(data, function(i,item){
                            newseries.name = item.name;
                            newseries.x = item.x;
                            newseries.y = item.y;

                            console.log(newseries)
                            series.addPoint(newseries, redrawVal, shiftVal);

                        });

                    };
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Using WebSockets for realtime updates'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'date'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'series',
        data: []
        }]

    });
});
```

Can someone help me get multiple series to dynamically display in highcharts.js?

Comment: this may look promising, will look further into it tomorrow:
http://jsfiddle.net/MMjN2/6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general idea should be that for each series you set it's `id`. Then you cna get that series this way: `chart.get(id)`. So if you have series, then add point to that series, if not, then create new one, just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9FkJc/8/

```
            var self = this;
            data = [{
                "y": 91,
                    "x": 1403640998,
                    "name": "parser1"
            }, {
                "y": 184,
                    "x": 1403640998,
                    "name": "parser2"
            }, {
                "y": 26,
                    "x": 1403640998,
                    "name": "parser3"
            }];

            var series = self.series[0];
            var redrawVal = true;

            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                var series = self.get(item.name);
                if (series) { // series already exists
                    series.addPoint(item, redrawVal, series.data.length > 25);
                } else { //  new series
                    self.addSeries({
                        data: [item],
                        id: item.name
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: was not aware of .addSeries.  Thanks for your help, you rock!